# Seleccionar un select y automáticamente me cambie el texto en un input con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un select y necesito que cuando por ejemplo seleccione Parcial el campo txtColor me ponga automaticamente el nombre de un color ejemplo azul, o si selecciono Final el campo txtColor me ponga Amarillo, o si selecciono el campo QA el txtColor me ponga Negro, pero no se como hacerlo.

```
<select name="milista" id="milista">
  <option value="1">Parcial</option>
  <option value="2">Final</option>
  <option value="3">QA</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="txtColor" id="txtColor" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
$("#milista").change(function() {
  var valor = $(this).val();
  switch (valor) {
    case '1': 
        $("#txtColor").val("Azul");
        break;
    case '2': 
        $("#txtColor").val("Amarillo");
        break;
    case '3': 
        $("#txtColor").val("Negro");
        break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="milista" id="milista">
  <option value="1">Parcial</option>
  <option value="2">Final</option>
  <option value="3">QA</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="txtColor" id="txtColor" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias SI ME SIRVIÓ.